# In Android, I'm Trying to Fetch Data From a URL To Plot on a Map, but I'm Having Problems Even Getting it To Print

Tags: android, request, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to fetch some data from online, which is in CSV format, however, I am getting an extremely long amount of errors in my log cat monitor and now I can't even get it to display those anymore. It won't return the data and crashes when attempting to plot it on the map.

Here's My Code For The Thread That Performs The Fetch:

```
package com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com
        .google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.WeightedLatLng;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;

/**
 * Created by Alex Levine on 8/14/2017.
 */

public class fetchFFDASData extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, List<String[]>> {
    public static ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> ffdasArray;

    protected List<String[]> doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        String typekey;

        ffdasArray = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
        Object[] ffdasObjects = null;
        URL mUrl = null;
        List<String[]> csvLine = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] content = null;
        try {
            //mUrl = new URL("http://hpcg.purdue.edu/FFDAS/Download/"+MainActivity.typeKey+"_yearly_date="+MainActivity.displayyear+"s-01-01-00_res=0.1_origin=-180,90_size=360,-180.csv");
            mUrl = new URL ("http://hpcg.purdue.edu/FFDAS/Download/" + MainActivity.typeKey + "_yearly_date=" + MainActivity.displayyear + "-01-01-00_res=0.1_origin=-180,90_size=360,-180.csv");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //assert mUrl != null;
            URLConnection connection = mUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                content = line.split(",");
                csvLine.add(content);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 3; i < /*csvLine.size()*/7; i++) {
            double lt = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[0]);
            double ln = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[2]);
            double w = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[2]);
            LatLng ltln = new LatLng(lt, ln);
            WeightedLatLng wll = new WeightedLatLng(ltln, w);
            ffdasArray.add(wll);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String[]> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //
        }
    }
```

Here Is My Main Activity:

```
 package com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.WeightedLatLng;

import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.R.id.seekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static SeekBar seekbar;

    public static GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private HeatmapTileProvider mProvider;

    public static TextView minyear;
    public static TextView maxyear;
    public static TextView currentyeartext;
    public static int displayyear;
    public static boolean usingSOCAT;
    public static String typeKey;
    public static Spinner dropdown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (googleServicesAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Play services available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            initMap();

            //get the spinner from the xml.
            dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            //create a list of items for the spinner.
            String[] items = new String[]{"Ocean CO2 Densities", "Land CO2 Emissions (all sources)", "Electricity CO2 Emissions", "Aviation CO2 Emissions", "Ocean Shipping CO2 Emissions"};
            //create an adapter to describe how the items are displayed, adapters are used in several places in android.
            //There are multiple variations of this, but this is the basic variant.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
            //set the spinners adapter to the previously created one.
            dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);


            currentyeartext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentyear);

            minyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minyear);
            maxyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxyear);

            typeKey = "00totals";
            dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0: {
                            usingSOCAT = true;
                            displayyear = 1957;
                            seekbar.setMax(58);
                            minyear.setText("1957");
                            maxyear.setText("2015");
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1: {
                            usingSOCAT = false;
                            displayyear = 1997;
                            minyear.setText("1997");
                            maxyear.setText("2010");
                            seekbar.setMax(14);
                            typeKey = "00totals";
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            usingSOCAT = false;
                            displayyear = 1997;
                            minyear.setText("1997");
                            maxyear.setText("2010");
                            seekbar.setMax(14);
                            typeKey = "01elec";

                            // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3: {
                            usingSOCAT = false;
                            displayyear = 1997;
                            minyear.setText("1997");
                            maxyear.setText("2010");
                            seekbar.setMax(14);
                            typeKey = "11aviation";;
                            // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4: {
                            usingSOCAT = false;
                            displayyear = 1997;
                            minyear.setText("1997");
                            maxyear.setText("2010");
                            seekbar.setMax(14);
                            typeKey = "12shipping";
                            // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {

                }
            });

            seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(seekBar);
            seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                    new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                            displayyear = progress + 1997;
                            if(usingSOCAT)
                            {
                                displayyear = progress + 1957;
                                new fetchSOCATData().execute();
                                //createHeatMap(fetchSOCATData.co2array);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                displayyear = progress + 1997;
                                new fetchFFDASData().execute();
                                //List<WeightedLatLng> calledData = fetchFFDASData.ffdasArray;
                                //List<WeightedLatLng> tryit = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
                                /*tryit.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(62, 42), 99));
                                tryit.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(86, 42), 14));
                                tryit.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(94, 42), 82));
                                tryit.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(71, 42), 22));
                                tryit.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(21, 42), 23));*/
                                //createHeatMap(fetchFFDASData.ffdasArray);
                                minyear.setText((CharSequence) fetchFFDASData.ffdasArray);
                            }
                            currentyeartext.setText("Showing: " + displayyear);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });

            if(usingSOCAT) {

            }
            //new fetchSOCATData().execute();
            /*minyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minyear);
            maxyear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxyear);
            minyear.setText("1957");
            maxyear.setText("2015");*/

            //fetchSOCATData process = new fetchSOCATData();
            //process.execute();

        } else {
            //No maps layout
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void initMap() {
       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);

       if(mapFragment != null) {
           mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback)this);
       }
    }

    public void createHeatMap(List<WeightedLatLng> dataset)
    {
       List<WeightedLatLng> locations = dataset;
       /*mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().weightedData(locations).build();
       mProvider.setRadius( HeatmapTileProvider.DEFAULT_RADIUS );
       mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
        mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider();
        mProvider.setWeightedData(dataset);
        mProvider = mProvider.build();*/

        //for (LatLng coordinate : coordinates) {
            //WeightedLatLng weightedCoordinate = new WeightedLatLng(coordinate);
            //com.google.maps.android.geometry.Point point = weightedCoordinate.getPoint();

            // Filter points at infinity
           /* if (Double.isInfinite(point.x) || Double.isInfinite(point.y)) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Attempted to add undefined point " + coordinate);
                continue;
            }
            weightedCoordinates.add(weightedCoordinate);*/
        //}

        mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                .weightedData(dataset)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .build();
        mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
        Toast.makeText(this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        goToLocation(-65, -12);
    }

    public void goToLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public boolean googleServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            return true;
        else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
            dialog.show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }


}
```

Please note that there are calls to other methods in the MainActivity which I have excluded in this post because they are not relevant, so that's not an error. However, could someone please take a look at my code and help me debug this? Thanks!

EDITED: Here's my log from where the error starts:

I saw some information on memory allocation, but I highly doubt that their is a huge overflow because I'm only calling like 4 lines of data to test this. Also, previously, there was some type of error displaying about some missing header, but I can't recreate it anymore.

```
08-29 01:05:22.311 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.873s for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.311 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 32B allocation
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11380/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 4.880s for cause HeapTrim
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.472s for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:22.312 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.313 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 40 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM, max allowed footprint 402653184, growth limit 402653184"
08-29 01:05:22.313 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 27.854s for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.313 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:22.313 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:22.313 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:22.318 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:22.318 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:23.535 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Clamp target GC heap from 389MB to 384MB
08-29 01:05:23.535 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 383MB/384MB, paused 553us total 1.222s
08-29 01:05:23.535 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.496s for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:23.535 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 8 free bytes and 8B until OOM, max allowed footprint 402653184, growth limit 402653184" (recursive case)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.223s for cause Alloc
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: "JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Runnable
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12c467e8 self=0xa7c0bc00
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | sysTid=11376 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x96aea970
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | state=R schedstat=( 29027554235 2495307398 3483 ) utm=2703 stm=199 core=0 HZ=100
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | stack=0x969f0000-0x969f2000 stackSize=1006KB
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:474)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:290)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:740)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:648)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:636)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:627)
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:23.536 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: JNI WARNING: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown while calling printStackTrace
08-29 01:05:23.537 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:23.538 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:25.781 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Clamp target GC heap from 389MB to 384MB
08-29 01:05:25.781 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 10(728B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 383MB/384MB, paused 1.299ms total 2.245s
08-29 01:05:25.781 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.781 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:25.781 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:25.782 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.782 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.469s for cause Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.782 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.782 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 3.469s for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:25.782 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM, max allowed footprint 402653184, growth limit 402653184" (recursive case)
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11379/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11376/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.783 11369-11369/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11856/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: "FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=9 Runnable
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12c863f0 self=0xa5263a00
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | sysTid=11378 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x968e8970
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | state=R schedstat=( 16464684522 913376415 1721 ) utm=1514 stm=132 core=0 HZ=100
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | stack=0x967e6000-0x967e8000 stackSize=1038KB
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:53)
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
08-29 01:05:25.784 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-29 01:05:25.786 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-29 01:05:25.786 11369-11378/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
```

Comment: can you post the error log

Comment: I posted the error log with some updated info. Can someone please help me determine the problem? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually using async task you could use library to handle your network calls like http://square.github.io/okhttp/

If you are going to use async task are doing it wrong when accessing the static array from the object of async task. instead override the post execute and then set the data in your activity

```
public class fetchFFDASData extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>> {
    public static ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> ffdasArray;

    protected List<String[]> doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        String typekey;

        ffdasArray = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
        Object[] ffdasObjects = null;
        URL mUrl = null;
        List<String[]> csvLine = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] content = null;
        try {
            //mUrl = new URL("http://hpcg.purdue.edu/FFDAS/Download/"+MainActivity.typeKey+"_yearly_date="+MainActivity.displayyear+"s-01-01-00_res=0.1_origin=-180,90_size=360,-180.csv");
            mUrl = new URL ("http://hpcg.purdue.edu/FFDAS/Download/" + MainActivity.typeKey + "_yearly_date=" + MainActivity.displayyear + "-01-01-00_res=0.1_origin=-180,90_size=360,-180.csv");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //assert mUrl != null;
            URLConnection connection = mUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                content = line.split(",");
                csvLine.add(content);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 3; i < /*csvLine.size()*/7; i++) {
            double lt = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[0]);
            double ln = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[2]);
            double w = Double.parseDouble(csvLine.get(i)[2]);
            LatLng ltln = new LatLng(lt, ln);
            WeightedLatLng wll = new WeightedLatLng(ltln, w);
            ffdasArray.add(wll);
        }
        return ffdasArray;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //
        }
    }
```

Now your call to async task in Activity will be

```
else
   {
     displayyear = progress + 1997;
     new fetchFFDASData(){
@ovveride
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
// minyear.setText();
        // do the processing here.
        }
    }
}.execute();


}
```